# How to violate Comparable interface first provision with integers overflow?

Tags: java, comparable, effective-java

`java.lang.Comparable#compareTo` method states as first provision

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compare-
>   To(x)) for all x and y. (This implies that x.compareTo(y) must throw
>   an exception if and only if y.compareTo(x) throws an exception.)

and according Joshua Bloch in Effective Java in item 12

> This trick works fine here but should be used with extreme caution.
>   Don’t use it unless you’re certain the fields in question are
>   non-negative or, more generally, that the difference between the
>   lowest and highest possible field values is less than or equal to
>   Integer.MAX_VALUE (231-1). The reason this trick doesn’t always work
>   is that a signed 32-bit integer isn’t big enough to hold the
>   difference between two arbitrary signed 32-bit integers. If i is a
>   large positive int and j is a large negative int, (i - j) will
>   overflow and return a negative value. The resulting compareTo method
>   will return incorrect results for some arguments and violate the first
>   and second provisions of the compareTo contract. This is not a purely
>   theoretical problem: it has caused failures in real systems. These
>   failures can be difficult to debug, as the broken compareTo method
>   works properly for most input values.

With integers overflow you can violate the first provision and I can't find how, this example shows how the first provision would be violated:

```
public class ProblemsWithLargeIntegers implements Comparable<ProblemsWithLargeIntegers> {

    private int zas;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ProblemsWithLargeIntegers o) {
        return zas - o.zas;
    }

    public ProblemsWithLargeIntegers(int zas) {
        this.zas = zas;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int value1 = ...;
      int value2 = ...;
      ProblemsWithLargeIntegers d = new ProblemsWithLargeIntegers(value1);
      ProblemsWithLargeIntegers e = new ProblemsWithLargeIntegers(value2);
      if (!(Math.signum(d.compareTo(e)) == -Math.signum(e.compareTo(d)))){
        System.out.println("hey!");
    }

}
```

So I want a `value1` and a `value2` for getting that? Any idea? Or Joshua was wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this violates the general contract to start with. For example, take `value1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `value2 = 1`. That will report that `Integer.MIN_VALUE > 1`, effectively.

EDIT: Actually, I was wrong - it's easy to violate the first provision:

```
int value1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int value2 = 0;
```

You'll get a negative result for both comparisons, because `Integer.MIN_VALUE - 0` == `0 - Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: yes, it is true, but not the first provision, and that't what I'm trying to get

Comment: Thanks that's right... but after testing the values you provided I found that `Integer.MIN_VALUE == -Integer.MIN_VALUE` is `true`... now I'm confused

Comment: @Jaime: Yes, that's right. Look at the exact range of supported values, and then think about what other result it could give...